# Is it safe to use JWT token for initial authentication but then express session from then on?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

I'm looking at using Firebase authentication (essentially JWT) with my React and express application and I wondering about the sanity/safety of mixing it with long-term session management.

The reason I'm thinking about this is because Firebase is free and very easy to integrate. However, verifying the JWT token server-side is an expensive call that I don't think is supposed to be performed on every request. Firebase offers a secure cookie, but there is a max ttl of 2 weeks. My app doesn't need that much security and I think the majority of my users would be annoyed if I asked them to re-authenticate every 2 weeks so I'm looking at a better solution.

So here's my thought:

1. User authenticates with Google/Firebase and front-end gets the token.
2. Front-end sends token to back-end and back-end verifies token with Google and checks that log in time was recent.
3. Back-end then creates or gets user from my db and sets the user id in a long lasting express session and all subsequent requests use that (except in the case of something rash like deleting your account where I would require the token again).

Essentially this is using the token to do the initial authentication/verification, but afterwards using the standard express session.

As far as I can tell, this really isn't different from what passport does after authenticating. But I would appreciate some verification that this is relatively safe given that it's over HTTPS and I protect against CSRF.

The biggest problem I can see is that it's not as safe as the token method in the case of theft because of the token's shorter lived nature, but is it any worse than using passport and having to store my user credentials myself?

So is this safe or stupid?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to put the user's UID in a session cookie?  If I know a user's UID, what's stopping me from injecting that value directly into the request to bypass any sort of authentication?

Comment: Well, I'm using express session so my understanding is that I'm putting a signed session ID in the cookie, and that's used on the server to pull the user data from the session store. I was under the impression that passportJS does the same thing. Also wouldn't good csrf protection help prevent that?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be saving any firebase data in the session store. Only my own db's user id and username.

Comment: Are you planning on validating the signature of the session cookie on every request? That might not be all that different from calling `verifyIdToken()` on every request. Have you done any performance tests to validate your assumptions? Also think about cases like user changing their password, or cases where you'd have to revoke an existing login session.